# Why does Vim cuts off UTF-8 characters?

Tags: vim, notepad++

I am trying to get the utf-8 checkbox character in the text editor. I can see it fine in both Notepad and Notepad++. But vim cuts off the character (check out attached picture). Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't just a problem of the font? Vim's one seems to be different than the one used by NPP.

Comment: no. it is an identical font. I am using `inconsolata`. but when I use other monospaced fonts for both. It does that same thing.